# convert screen hardstatus to tmux

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I'm a longtime screen user, but the move to tmux is growing inevitable.

I have a fairly large .screenrc that I am working toward porting to tmux (I'd like the bulk of my existing workflow to just continue working)

Most of it I can do with relatively little work, but my hardstatus is quite involved and due to the nature of screen I'm not even 100% sure how it works. It's a hack job butchered together from the good bits of other peoples.

Is there a tool/procedure for converting one to the other? Should there be?

Comment: "hack job butchered together..." Look to your left brother, for I am singing in the same choir.

Comment: I added my final results as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my tmux config, and the screenrc that I was trying to emulate when I wrote it.

https://github.com/richo/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf

https://github.com/richo/dotfiles/blob/master/screenrc

Comment: Files are no longer available. Would it be possible to post them here?

Comment: Sure, one second.